# Mockito Uri.parse always returns null

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I have this production method:

```
public boolean onShouldOverrideUrlLoading(String url) {
    boolean isConsumed = false;
    if (url.contains("code=")) {
         Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
         String authCode = uri.getQueryParameter("code");
         mView.authCodeObtained(authCode);
         isConsumed = true;
    }
    return isConsumed;
}
```

And I have this Mockito test method:

```
@Test
public void onShouldOverrideUrlLoadingOnAuthCodeObtained(){

    String code = "someCode";

    boolean isConsumed = mPresenter.onShouldOverrideUrlLoading("http://localhost/?code=" + code);

    verify(mView, times(1)).authCodeObtained(code);
    assertEquals(isConsumed, true);
}
```

But it seems once the code runs and it reaches Uri.parse(url), I get a null pointer. What am I missing? In production this works perfectly. Only when testing, Uri.parse() returns null.

Thank you!

Comment: The problem is probably in Uri, it probably badly initialize in the test environment. We `Uri` does not exists in the Android SDK [`URI`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URI.html#create(java.lang.String)) does. So it doesn't seem like a shipped class, this could be the issue. Nothing related to mockito.

Comment: @Brice Thank you. Yes that seemed to be the issue. You should post this as the answer.
The Uri class comes from Android. So Mockito has some difficulties working with it that way.

Comment: done :) Hope that helped.

Comment: @Alon How did you solve the problem exactly? How do I init my test environment correctly in Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem probably lies in `Uri` class, as the code being tested is static code (`Uri.parse(...)`), `Uri` is probably badly initializing in the test environment. Note there's two uri classes in the Android SDK :

- [`android.net.Uri`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html)
- [`java.net.URI`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URI.html#create(java.lang.String))

I'm not an Android developer, but you may want to check the test environment.

Comment: How did you solve the problem exactly? How do I init my test environment correctly in Android?

Comment: @user59442 I cannot answer you on this one, I'm not an _Android developer_. Ask the question's author Alon Minski instead!

Answer (score 23):

Eventually I used PowerMock on top of Mockito to mock the Uri class.
Use these dependecies to add it:

```
'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.4.12'
'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.2'
```

Read about it [here](https://github.com/jayway/powermock).

It enables you to mock static methods, private methods, final classes and more.
In my test method I used:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Uri.class);
Uri uri = mock(Uri.class);

PowerMockito.when(Uri.class, "parse", anyString()).thenReturn(uri);
```

This passed the line in the actual code and returned a Mocked Uri object so the test could move forward.
Make sure to add:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Uri.class})
```

As annotations on top of the test class name.

Using Robolectric to tackle this issue is also a valid technique.

Hope this helps some what.

Answer (score 8):

I got around this by using the Roboelectric test runner.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner::class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig::class, sdk = intArrayOf(19))
class WeekPageViewModelConverterTests {
...
}
```

Comment: My equivalent way to write this in Java, to the above Kotlin, is:

`@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)`
`public class ExampleUnitTest {`

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is the fact that `android.jar` file that is used to run unit tests does not contain any actual code.
This way `android.net.Uri` will return `null` by default and using

```
android {
  // ...
  testOptions { 
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
  }
}
```

will not solve the issue for this case, since default return value for method still `null`

The solution for me was to use the [Unmock](https://github.com/bjoernQ/unmock-plugin) plugin which sole purpose is to unmock some of the classes/packages from `android.jar` and give the full implementation for those.

In this specific case, simply add the snippet to you `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'de.mobilej.unmock'
 //...
unMock {
    keepStartingWith "android.net.Uri"
}
```

Comment: This worked, but I had to give additional keep rules 

    unMock {
       keep "android.net.Uri"
       keepAndRename "java.nio.charset.Charsets" to "xjava.nio.charset.Charsets"
       keepStartingWith "libcore."
    }

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem by running the test suite with "@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)"

Comment: when I added this library my test is gonna keep building for several minutes and I can't see the result any more

Comment: finnally it works, for first building in gonna last a long time in my case it was nearly 20 minutes .Thanks for this approach...........

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else looking, you can mock a Uri using mockito.

In kotlin:

```
mockkStatic(Uri::class)
every { Uri.parse(any()) } returns mockk()
```

[Here](https://rieckpil.de/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito-java-kotlin/) is a link with more info on mocking static methods.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem doing tests with `android.net.Uri` class.

I've solved the problem moving the test from the 'test' folder to 'androidTest' and running it in the device. In the device, the `Uri` class behaves normally.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use `android.net.Uri` using `AndroidJUnit4` runner as follows

```kotlin
import androidx.core.net.toUri
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
...
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class FileTest {
  @get:Rule(order = 0)
  val tempFolder = TemporaryFolder()
  private lateinit var tempFile: File

  @Before
  fun setup() {
    tempFile = tempFolder.newFile()
  }

  @Test
  fun test_fileUri_not_null() {
    assertTrue(tempFile.exists())
    assertNotNull(tempFile.toUri())
  }
}
```

*Above test is written under `tests` directory*

Comment: Getting error for tempFile.toUri() :  Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6. Please specify proper '-jvm-target' option

Answer (score 0):

If you use the android.net.Uri class, then you need to run your tests with Robolectric (http://robolectric.org) on top of Mockito

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me was the following, while using `powermockito`.

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Uri.class);
Uri uri = mock(Uri.class);
when(uri.getLastPathSegment()).thenReturn("path");

when(Uri.parse(anyString())).thenAnswer((Answer<Uri>) invocation -> uri);
```

In this, we can set custom values to be returned by respective functions of uri object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the android jar that's used during unit test runs doesn't have any real implementations. We can do the following to use a proper implementation of Uri:

- Add `"com.github.bjoernq:unmockplugin:x.x.x"` to the `classpath` in the project's or module's `buildScript`
- Add `de.mobilej.unmock` in the `plugin` block as an `id`
- Add the following task:

  unmock {
  keep("android.net.Uri")
  }
- Run your unit test. Uri methods should start working.