# Uri.parse() always returns null in unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, uri

This simple unit test always passes and I can't figure out why.

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
class SampleTest {
    @Test testSomething() {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("myapp://home/payments");
        assertTrue(uri == null);
    }
}
```

What I have tried so far is using a "traditional" URI (`http://example.com`) but `uri` was also `null`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Check if you have the following in your app's gradle file:

```
android {
    ...
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
```

`Uri` is an Android class and as such cannot be used in local unit tests, without the code above you get the following:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method parse in android.net.Uri not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
```

The code above suppresses this exception and instead provides dummy implementations returning default values (`null` in this case).

The other option is that you are using some framework in your tests that provides implementations of the methods in Android classes.

Comment: I stated in my OP that the test passes so there's no exception thrown. Moreover I not only need a non-null Uri object, I need a Uri object with specific properties (scheme, path, etc.)

Answer (score 64):

I resolve this problem with [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/).

these are my unit test config

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
...
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.4.2"
}
```

test class

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class TestClass {
    
    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
      Uri uri = Uri.parse("anyString")
      //then do what you want, just like normal coding
    }
}
```

kotlin

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class TestClass {
   @Test
   fun testFunction() {
      val uri = Uri.parse("anyString")
      //then do what you want, just like normal coding
   }
}
```

it works for me, hope this can help you.

Comment: Why the -1 on this? In my mind, this is the actual correct answer because Robolectric gives you an actual implementation of Uri, not just a mock, along with implementations of everything else you'll need to unit test Android.

Comment: In recent version for `kotlin` you will have to use this `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)`

Comment: If `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)` does not work for you, please check the import. Use `import org.junit.runner.RunWith` instead of `import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`

Answer (score 7):

Uri is Android class therefore it needs to be mocked before using in tests.

See this answer for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34152256/5199320

Answer (score 2):

This was dumb...but I forgot to annotate my test class with: `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)`

Once I did that, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

[Use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22059289/2914140) `URL` class instead of `Uri`.

```
import java.net.URL

fun getDomain(url: String): String {
    return URL(url).host
}

-------------

@Test
fun test() {
    Assert.assertEquals("www.ru", getDomain("https://www.ru"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I just changed my code to accept URIs as `String`, so now it works both in production and test and omit the usage of `Uri.parse()`. Now where an URI is needed I just use `uri.toString()` instead of parsing a `String`.

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea. By using Uri you provide a higher level of type safely compared to strings. Strings can contain anything, with a Uri you know at least that it is a valid Uri. Your unit tests are supposed to increase your code quality, not decrease it. I would rather turn this test into a connected (Espresso) test.

Comment: Thanks, I understood that `Uri.parse` is Android-dependant method and removed it from code.

Answer (score 0):

Below code solved my problem.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@Config(sdk = [Build.VERSION_CODES.P])
class TestClass
```