# Unit test - Uri is always null

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

I have entity:

```
data class BaseItem(
    val id: Long = 0,
    val name: String = "",
    val description: String = "",
    val uri: Uri = Uri.EMPTY,
    val active: Boolean = true,
    val done: Boolean = false,
    val date: LocalDate? = null,
    val plantId: Long = 0
)
```

and viewModel method I would like to test:

```
fun getEmptyUiState(): Pair<BaseItem, List<BaseItem>> {
    return Pair(BaseItem(), listOf<BaseItem>())
}
```

Test method:

```
@Test
fun getEmptyUiState() {
    val emptyUiState = viewModel.getEmptyUiState()
    assertThat(emptyUiState).isEqualTo(Pair(BaseItem(), listOf<BaseItem>()))
}
```

I always get:
EMPTY must not be null
java.lang.NullPointerException: EMPTY must not be null
at com.rachapps.uielements.dto.BaseItem.(BaseItem.kt:11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `Uri` is part of the Android SDK and can't be easily tested using Unit Tests.

The only solution is to use PowerMock, as explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34152256/2310221

Comment: Thx. I annotated class with :
@RunWith(
    RobolectricTestRunner::class
) and it also helped